# XAMPP server not displaying echo

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

I am new to XAMPP as I have used WAMP previously and I am a bit stuck.

I have installed XAMPP and I have both Apache and SQL running (confirmed by green boxes next to Apache and MySQL when I start XAMPP). In Apache httpd.conf I have had to change the port number from 80 to 8080 because port 80 is used by IIS. Again I have confirmed all this is working by going to localhost:8080. In here I see the following welcome screen.
[image]

When I click on the English version I see the following screen.
[image]

I WAMP I am used to seeing the following screen.
[image]

Am I supposed to see the same root navigation in XAMPP as I am seeing in WAMP?

The reason I ask is when I try to run the following php test, I dont see the fist echo test.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p>                       // This is working 
<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>             // This is NOT working
<?php echo '<p>Hello World now </p>'; ?>  // This is working 
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Check your xampp status and make sure it is running and apache service is started.

Comment: OK solved the code issue. Feeling rather stupid. The error was that the .css was set to black background and white text for p-elements. Hence the first echo was showing up but I couldnt see default black font on black background. Sorry for wasting time. Can anyone clarify the root menu difference thought please?

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to say. You need the root menu difference .. It means ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. All I wanted to know does XAMPP provide a easy root navigation to projects as WAMP does as in the image? In WAMP you have a list of sites under the "Your Projects" section which makes jumping between jobs very easy. I cant see similar in XAMPP so I have to type localhost:8080/myNewSite/index.php each time? Sorry, maybe Im just being lazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your projects by

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/
->projectone/index.php
->projecttwo/home.php
```

You can access it by

```
localhost/projectone
localhost/projecttwo/home.php
```

Here is the [Tutorialspoint Tutorial to use xampp easily.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server)

And you don't need any permissions to run your project folder.